# Rx.NET: this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Foo) in constructor throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a class in which I'm doing something similar to the following:

```
public class Foo : ReactiveObject
{
    // The constructor that sets up a subscription
    public Foo()
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue(foo => foo.Bar)
            .Where(bar => bar != null)
            .Subscribe(bar => ...);
    }

    // Reactive property
    private IBar _bar;
    public IBar Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _bar, value); }
    }
}
```

Now, upon construction of the instance, I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dispatcher
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CoreDispatcherScheduler..ctor(CoreDispatcher dispatcher)}
```

To make sure that I'm not doing something stupid with my instance, I've split up the subscription in parts, just for testing:

```
var observable = this.WhenAnyValue(foo => foo.Bar); // <-- throws already on this line!
var nonulls = observable.Where(bar => bar != null);
var subscription = nonulls.Subscribe(bar => ...);
```

I can't find a way to get a better view of what's going wrong here. How do I get more information about this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: Does the static property even do anything? Try removing everything that is not related. I would also try to call a base constructor before doing anything else.

Comment: @manuFS: What do you mean "does it even do anything?" I'm including it because the instantiation of my object is done through accessing `Foo.Instance` rather than calling the constructor explicitly. Also, there are no base constructors to call (only a protected empty one, which is already called implicitly).

Comment: @manuFS: Now I noticed the typo with the static property; please see the update.

Comment: I mean, have you tried making it a public ctor, just to see if it's because of the static init.

Comment: @manuFS: Tried that now, still throws.

Comment: What is the context in which the class is instantiated? (e.g. threadpool, background-thread, ui-thread, is it on app-start or later)

Comment: It's triggered at the startup of a Windows Phone 8.1 app (i.e. from the constructor of the `App` class).

Comment: Have you tried moving it to some "OnLoaded" callback? (don't know how it is referenced)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.  For some reason, the dispatcher is not available.  Knowing who/what is constructing the `CoreDispatcherScheduler` would help to track down the culprit.

Comment: @manuFS: Moving it to the `OnLaunched` method did indeed help! Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness' sake I'll pull an answer from the comments:

It appears that the `CoreDispatcherScheduler` was not yet created at the time when you started observing your properties. In my experience, these things tend to happen when you use observables in constructors, which then may be used quite early in the application lifecycle.

So, moving the instantiation to the `OnLaunched` event, instead of the app startup, could help. When possible, I try to use `Init()` functions instead of constructors to wire up my observables.